# How can I insert rows to Pandas dataframe depending on previous and next values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to insert a row if the time values between the previous and next rows are high. Essentially I want to have a row for every 2 seconds. So in the below example I want to add 3 rows between 19 and 26. The time values will be 21, 23, 25 and I will later use interpolate method to fill X values for that rows.

| Time | X |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 150 |
| 16 | 172 |
| 16 | 175 |
| 18 | 193 |
| 19 | 190 |
| 26 | 232 |

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `append` a list of `dict`:

```
df.append([{'Time':i} for i in range(21,26,2)], 
          ignore_index=True).sort_values('Time')
```